# How to get a signal when the widget size changes

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I need to perform an operation when the size of a widget (`MyForm`) changes.

Is there a signal which is emitted when the size of a widget changes? (I could not find it in the documentation).

I need to do something like this:

```
#include "myform.h"
#include "ui_myform.h"

MyForm::MyForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(this, SIGNAL(sizeChanged()), this, SLOT(refresh()));
}

MyForm::~MyForm()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MyForm::refresh()
{
    ui->label->setText( QString::number(this->width()) + ", " + QString::number(this->height()));
}
```

When the widget size changes, it 'calls' the `refresh` function which updates a label with the current **width** and **height**. **Note**: it is only an example which can be easily reproduced.

---

Sure I can use a `QTimer`, for example:

```
#include "myform.h"
#include "ui_myform.h"

MyForm::MyForm(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MyForm)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    timer_ = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer_, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(refresh()));

    timer_->start(100);
}

MyForm::~MyForm()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MyForm::refresh()
{
    ui->label->setText( QString::number(this->width()) + ", " + QString::number(this->height()));
}
```

But I don't think it is the best solution.

**Note**: I'm using Qt 5.3.

Comment: You need to override [`QWidget::resizeEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not necessary to create a signal, you just have to overwrite `resizeEvent()` and call refresh from that method:

***.h**

```
protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event);
```

***.cpp**

```
void MyForm::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event)
{
    refresh();
    QWidget::resizeEvent(event);
}
```